# how to remove a string from a code using methods, arrays and loops?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I made a code that removes symbols and characters from a "string text" using "method" and "arrays" and "loops", and everything was built in successfully.

But, when I tried testing it on an actual String text, it wasn't running. Someone clarify what I did wrong. here is the code:

```
public static String remove(String text, char symbol){
    String a= " ";
    for(int i=1; i<text.length();i++){
        char letter=text.charAt(i);
        if(letter !=symbol){
            a+=letter;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: _i asked multiple professors to help but they didn't know as well_ that's interesting

Comment: exactly that's why i asked.

Comment: What does "it wasn't running" mean? It's not called (in which case the client code would be more important to see)? It throws an exception (which one)? It returns an unexpected result (which one and with what inputs)?

Comment: lets say the client wrote a text for example // String text= "helloxxxoooworld" // and the client wants to remove the x's and the o's so it turns to // "hello world" // and i wrote a code for that yet it wasn't applying

Comment: And, again, what does "it wasn't applying" mean?

Comment: the code is not working on an actual string but running successfully

Comment: so when the client writes a text it wouldn't be able to remove the symbols or characters

Comment: It is running for me. The problem seems to be with the way how you call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. `a = " "` doesn't seem to be correct, unless you want to have a space at the beginning of the result-string.
2. The iteration in your for-loop starts at `i = 1`. That's not correct either, because that way you will not work on the first letter in the string.

A corrected - and working - solution looks like this:

```
public class RemoveLetter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(remove("Hello World", 'o')); 
    }
    public static String remove(String text, char symbol){
        String a= "";
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            char letter = text.charAt(i);
            if(letter != symbol) {
                a += letter;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

This example will give the output `Hell Wrld`, which certainly is correct.

**Edit** To remove more than one letter, you will have to call the method multiple times:

```
public class RemoveLetter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "Hello World";
        String result = remove(string, 'o');
        result = remove(result, 'H');
        System.out.println(result);  
    }
    public static String remove(String text, char symbol){
        String a= "";
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            char letter = text.charAt(i);
            if(letter != symbol) {
                a += letter;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

This will give you the output `ell Wrld`.

Comment: but i used a method i made and not the main method, as well as using arrays

Comment: Every java-program absolutely needs a main-method. This way the computer knows where to start the program. Where did you use arrays? I don't see an array in your code.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer helped you, I would appreciate if you accept it (click on the green checkmark besides this answer). That's the standard way (together with upvoting) to say "thank you" to the answer that helped you the most on stackoverflow.

Comment: but lets say the text has two character that wants to be removed for example // String text= ""xxxgoodxxxluckxxxxooo"; and the client wants to remove x and o?

Comment: @ghosthunter They would call the function twice with different parameters, the second time with the string returned from the first call.

Comment: Just added an example. Does that help?

Comment: @ghosthunter learn about `varargs` if you want to use multiple passing characters.

Comment: i just ran and the code and had a problem with // System.out.println(remove(result));  //

Comment: I just corrected it. Please reload the page and copy the code again.

Comment: @natsu im still a beginner in coding we cant use codes we still didn't learn

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not 1, it should be 0. Try this code:

```
public static String remove(String text, char symbol) {

    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char letter = text.charAt(i);
        if (letter != symbol) {
            a.append(letter);
        }
    }
    return a.toString();
}
```